# How do I execute a function once per page refreshing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a code like this:

```
function myfunc () {
    alert('executed');
}

$('.classname').on('click' function () {
    myfunc();
});
```

I want to run `myfunc` once. I mean I don't want to execute it every time when user clicks on `.classname` element. I guess I need to warp function-calling into a condition. Something like this:

```
if ( /* that function never executed so far */ ) {
    myfunc();
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way with jQuery is to use [.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```js
function myfunc() {
  alert('executed');
  
}
 
$('.classname').one('click', function() {   
  myfunc(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button  class="classname">click here!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the event listener in the function you're calling:

```js
function myfunc () {
  alert('executed');
  $('.classname').off('click', myfunc);
}

$('.classname').on('click', myfunc);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class='classname'>Click Me</div>
```

Don't set a global variable like the other posts describe - there's no need for that and then you're still doing an unnecessary function call. This ensures the function is never called again and the event isn't being listed for.

Comment: Very clean solution, but note: this removes ALL click listeners for that element. If you have other functions bound to that click event they will be lost.

Comment: No, that is not correct. The click handler I've set calls a specific function.  If you were to add another onclick handler to another function, that would not be removed. See: https://jsfiddle.net/rf05xfub/

Comment: Oh nice, didn't realize you could use .off with a delegate. I stand corrected

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var hasBeenExecuted = false;

function myfunc () {
    alert('executed');
    hasBeenExecuted = true;
}

$('.classname').on('click' function () {
    if(!hasBeenExecuted){
       myfunc();
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var functionWasRun = false;

function myfunc () {
    functionWasRun = true;
    alert('executed');
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.classname').on('click', function () {
        if (!functionWasRun) {
         myfunc();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, as an alternative to a global variable, assigning a property to the function.

```
function myfunc () {
    alert('executed');
    myfunc.executed = true;
}

$('.classname').on('click', function () {
    if(!myfunc.executed) {
        myfunc();
    }
});
```

This has the advantage of working the same way while not polluting the global scope unnecessarily. However, if [skyline3000's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38731891/2789699) works for you, you should use that instead as it's cleaner and more sensible overall.